# Getting error while creating maven based project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am geeting this error after entering artifact id.

```
Could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.1 from any of the configured repositories.
Could not resolve artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced.
Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection refused: connect
```

Comment: add or link your error

Answer (score 0):

You need delete `${yourUser}/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/archetypes`

Comment: After deleting i am facing the same error